# Spring MVC 2.5 Using a mix of annotations & XML configuration but xml gets ignored

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, annotations, applicationcontext

In my Spring MVC webapplication I want to mix xml based configuration with annotations:
I use annotations like `@Controller`, `@RequestMapping("bla.htm")`, `@RequestParam` etc. to resolve `HttpRequest`s to `Controller` Methods. Therefore I added

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="somePackage.controller"/>
```

to my `dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

But my controllers have attributes. Those attributes could be injected via `@AutoWired` annotation. But I also have do define Scopes. So i would have two annotations per attribute, which makes the code bad readable. So I want to inject dependencies in my `applicationContext.xml` file.

Is there a way I can keep the annotation-driven request-mapping but use context.xml files for Dependency Injection? Or is it only possible to use EITHER annotations OR xml configuration?

note: my beans for dependency injection are in a different xml file.

PS:

I should have mentioned, I use Spring 2.5 and can't upgrade it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `<mvc:annotation-driven>` works fine with XML. But you'll need to get rid of the `<context:component-scan>`.

Update: with Spring 2.5, this should get you started:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

    <!-- now add some controllers -->

</beans>
```

Comment: @mosk It should work in 2.5, but "it doesn't work" is not really helpful. please update the question with the context you are now using

Comment: I edited my start post. Using <mvc:annotation-driven> leads to the error message, posted in my start-post.

Comment: @mosk Oops, sorry, I was wrong. The functionality exists in 2.5, but the mvc namespace doesn't. Upgrade to 3.x if you can

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is certainly possible.

To use the controller annotations such as `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping` make sure you put

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

in your `<servletname>-servlet.xml`

Then simple define your controllers using the normal XML bean notation such as:

```
<bean class="com.company.controllers.AController">
    <property name="propertyName" ref="beanId" />
</bean>
```

These bean refs can come from any other `applicationContext.xml` defined in your `web.xml` too.

Comment: Ah yes, you need Spring 3.0 for that. No worries though, just means you can't use the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` element. Just manually declare your `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and your `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` instead and it should work.

Comment: But i declared those two beans already. See my start-post. Or is there missing something in declaration?

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have been more specific. The `<mvc:annotation-driven>` element declares those two beans for you automatically. Since you're using Spring 2.5 you cannot use the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` shortcut anyway so you have to declare them both yourself in your `context.xml`. Just keep the two bean definitions mentioned above and everything should work.